# How to insert an EPS picture into a Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, graphics, eps

I want to insert this picture :[image: A picture]
in to a beamer. I know that there some problems if the picture is in the format of `PNG` or `jpeg`. So, I convert it into `eps` format. When I tried to insert it, it failed with many errors.
Can someone show me how to do this? As you can see that it's a little big.  How can it be scaled to suit beamer document?

Comment: Are you using pfdlatex to compile? If so, then `PNG` (or better yet, `PDF`) is the format to go. Why don't you write this directly, instead of using an image?

Comment: Why dont you just typeset yourself?  You can then align the math at the equal signs or you can keep it all centered if you prefer that.

Comment: I got error messages related to my eps figures when compiling my beamer file using pdflatex, but was able to compile it using latex and then using dvipdfmx to convert dvi to pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, where `figure-name` is the file name of your figure (without the file extension). If you have it in both PDF and EPS formats, then the compiler should automatically choose the right one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}

\frame
{
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.9\textwidth]{./figure-name}
    \caption{Awesome figure}
  \end{figure}

}

\end{document}
```

I've included the package [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) as it gives some useful options for figures. I've set the width of the figure to 90% of the text width. You can play around with that to get it to fit as you like. I've put the image in the `figure` environment and given it a caption, but you don't have to. `\centering` won't work outside the environment, but you could use instead:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width = 0.9\textwidth]{./figure-name}
\end{center}
```

If you don't care about centering, then you don't even need to bother with that. Hope that sorts things.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `eps` figures, you could try adding:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

in the preamble of your document.

This should automatically convert your `eps` into `pdfs` when compiling the document.